# Make soap client python with suds

Tags: python, soap, client, suds

I create this script in perl:

```
#!"c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;

my $message = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AddUser xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <HostUserName>hcadmin</HostUserName>
      <HostPassword>XXXXXXXXX</HostPassword>
      <OwnerName>hcadmin</OwnerName>
      <PlanName>Unlimited Plan - Windows</PlanName>
      <NewUserName>froyland</NewUserName>
      <NewUserPassword>XXXXXXX</NewUserPassword>
      <EmailAddress>john@hosting.net</EmailAddress>
      <ResellerType>Dedicated</ResellerType>
      </AddUser>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(POST => 'http://painel.a.nrserver.net:8080/UserManager.asmx');
$request->header(SOAPAction => '"http://tempuri.org/AddUser"');
$request->content($message);
$request->content_type("text/xml; charset=utf-8");
my $response = $userAgent->request($request);

if($response->code == 200) {
    print $response->as_string, '\n';
}
else {
    print $response->error_as_HTML;
}
```

Now I intend to do the same in python, I looked some components and found suds, but was unable to write something as simple as perl, did not yet have much experience with python, can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried *anything* with Python and suds? Show us the code!

Comment: You know, it could be a single line of code. Maybe you should [read the docs](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#BASICUSAGE) **before** resorting to SO. _Maybe_.

Answer (score 0):

I created sample scripts with suds, pysimplesoap, but they did not work as I would like, so I made something using urllib2 and it worked perfectly. I have problems because the url of my API is http://xxxxxx.com:8080/action.asmx and the httplib does not work.

Anyway thanks for answer.